LaTeX table issue: caption and adjustbox causing compilation error
I am creating a table in LaTeX using the adjustbox package to resize it to fit the page width. When I add a caption with the \caption command, the compilation fails.
If I remove the caption, the table compiles correctly. Below are the minimal working examples before and after adding the caption:
Code without caption (compiles correctly):
\begin{table}[t]
\caption{Test}
\small
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{c|cc|cc|cc|cc}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Method} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{RV}                            & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Myo}               & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{LV}                 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Avg.}               \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{adjustbox}
\label{tab:dmplscmipl}

\end{table}

Before adding caption
Code with caption (causes error):
\begin{table}[t]
\caption{Test}
\small
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{c|cc|cc|cc|cc}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Method} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{RV}                            & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Myo}               & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{LV}                 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Avg.}               \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{adjustbox}
\label{tab:dmplscmipl}

\end{table}

and the error occurs:
The errors
Environment:
LaTeX editor: Overleaf
Compiler: pdflatex
Relevant packages: adjustbox, caption.
Template: Springer Nature LaTeX Template Dec 2023
What did I try and what were you expecting?
I also tried the resizebox, the similiar error occurs:
Code with resizebox:
\begin{table}[t]
\label{tab:dmplscmipl}

\caption{Test}
\resizebox{.5\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{c|cc|cc|cc|cc}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Method} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{RV}                            & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Myo}               & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{LV}                 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Avg.}               \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}

and the error occurs:
Error
A compilable version of my code is:
sn-article.tex
\documentclass[pdflatex,sn-mathphys-num]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences 
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%
\usepackage{adjustbox} 

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\label{tab:dmplscmipl}

\caption{Test}
\begin{tabular}{c|cc|cc|cc|cc}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Method} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{RV}                            & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Myo}               & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{LV}                 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Avg.}               \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}

The code is based on the Springer Nature LaTeX Template, which is available at Springer Nature Template on Overleaf
While compiling the code:

\documentclass[pdflatex,sn-mathphys-num]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences 
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%
\usepackage{adjustbox} 

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\caption{table}{Segmentation outcomes between our method and other semi- or scribble-segmentation methods using 8 scribbles annotated ACDC cases. The best performance is denoted using bold, and the second-best performance is marked by underline. The results are presented in the form of ``mean(std)''.}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}

\begin{tabular}{c|cc|cc|cc|cc}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Method}            & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{RV}                              & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Myo}                    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{LV}                      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Avg.}                    \\

\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}

\end{document}


The error log was
Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.29 \end{tabular}
                  
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
Missing } inserted.
You need to enclose all mathematical expressions and symbols with special markers. These special markers create a ‘math mode’.

Use $...$ for inline math mode, and \[...\]or one of the mathematical environments (e.g. equation) for display math mode.

This applies to symbols such as subscripts ( _ ), integrals ( \int ), Greek letters ( \alpha, \beta, \delta ) and modifiers (\vec{x}, \tilde{x}).

Learn more
<inserted text> 
                }
l.29 \end{tabular}
                  
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
LaTeX Error: \begin{threeparttable} on input line 21 ended by \end{tabular}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.29 \end{tabular}
                  
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
LaTeX Error: \begin{center} on input line 21 ended by \end{adjustbox}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.30 \end{adjustbox}
                    
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
Missing } inserted.
You need to enclose all mathematical expressions and symbols with special markers. These special markers create a ‘math mode’.

Use $...$ for inline math mode, and \[...\]or one of the mathematical environments (e.g. equation) for display math mode.

This applies to symbols such as subscripts ( _ ), integrals ( \int ), Greek letters ( \alpha, \beta, \delta ) and modifiers (\vec{x}, \tilde{x}).

Learn more
<inserted text> 
                }
l.31 \end{table}
                
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
LaTeX Error: \begin{tableorg} on input line 21 ended by \end{threeparttable}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.31 \end{table}
                
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
LaTeX Error: \begin{table} on input line 21 ended by \end{center}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.31 \end{table}
                
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
Too many }'s.
\@endfloatbox ...pagefalse \outer@nobreak \egroup 
                                                  \color@endbox 
l.31 \end{table}
                
You've closed more groups than you opened.
Such booboos are generally harmless, so keep going.
Extra \endgroup.
\color@endgroup ->\endgraf \endgroup 
                                     
l.31 \end{table}
                
Things are pretty mixed up, but I think the worst is over.
Too many }'s.
\color@endbox ->\color@endgroup \egroup 
                                        
l.31 \end{table}
                
You've closed more groups than you opened.
Such booboos are generally harmless, so keep going.
LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{tableorg}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.31 \end{table}
                
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
Extra \endgroup.
<recently read> \endgroup 
                          
l.31 \end{table}
                
Things are pretty mixed up, but I think the worst is over.
LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{table}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.31 \end{table}
                
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

When compiling the code

\documentclass[pdflatex,sn-mathphys-num]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences 
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%
\usepackage{adjustbox} 

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\caption{table}{Segmentation outcomes between our method and other semi- or scribble-segmentation methods using 8 scribbles annotated ACDC cases. The best performance is denoted using bold, and the second-best performance is marked by underline. The results are presented in the form of ``mean(std)''.}
\resizebox{.9\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{c|cc|cc|cc|cc}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Method}            & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{RV}                              & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Myo}                    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{LV}                      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Avg.}                    \\

\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}

\end{document}


The error log was:
Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.29 }
      
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
Missing } inserted.
You need to enclose all mathematical expressions and symbols with special markers. These special markers create a ‘math mode’.

Use $...$ for inline math mode, and \[...\]or one of the mathematical environments (e.g. equation) for display math mode.

This applies to symbols such as subscripts ( _ ), integrals ( \int ), Greek letters ( \alpha, \beta, \delta ) and modifiers (\vec{x}, \tilde{x}).

Learn more
<inserted text> 
                }
l.29 }
      
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
LaTeX Error: \begin{threeparttable} on input line 21 ended by \end{tabular}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.29 }
      
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
Package graphics Error: Division by 0.
See the graphics package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.29 }
      
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
Missing } inserted.
You need to enclose all mathematical expressions and symbols with special markers. These special markers create a ‘math mode’.

Use $...$ for inline math mode, and \[...\]or one of the mathematical environments (e.g. equation) for display math mode.

This applies to symbols such as subscripts ( _ ), integrals ( \int ), Greek letters ( \alpha, \beta, \delta ) and modifiers (\vec{x}, \tilde{x}).

Learn more
<inserted text> 
                }
l.30 \end{table}
                
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\TPT@close ...\unskip \fi \color@endgroup \egroup 
                                                  
l.30 \end{table}
                
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
LaTeX Error: \begin{table} on input line 21 ended by \end{threeparttable}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.30 \end{table}
                
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{center}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.30 \end{table}
                
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
Extra \endgroup.
<recently read> \endgroup 
                          
l.30 \end{table}
                
Things are pretty mixed up, but I think the worst is over.
Too many }'s.
\@endfloatbox ...pagefalse \outer@nobreak \egroup 
                                                  \color@endbox 
l.30 \end{table}
                
You've closed more groups than you opened.
Such booboos are generally harmless, so keep going.
Extra \endgroup.
\color@endgroup ->\endgraf \endgroup 
                                     
l.30 \end{table}
                
Things are pretty mixed up, but I think the worst is over.
Too many }'s.
\color@endbox ->\color@endgroup \egroup 
                                        
l.30 \end{table}
                
You've closed more groups than you opened.
Such booboos are generally harmless, so keep going.
LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{tableorg}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.30 \end{table}
                
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{table}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.30 \end{table}
                
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.



Scaling elements which contain text, like tables, is usually a bad idea. Better choose a suitable font size and/or layout instead.

Thank you for your feedback!
I have updated my question to include a minimal working example with a complete and compilable LaTeX document. The code is based on the Springer Nature LaTeX Template, which is available at Springer Nature Template on Overleaf.

Your full example compile without error for me. But do you really think that it helps us to understand your error if you show a screenshot with red blots? Show the log-file.

It's really simple: sn-jnl redefines table in a way that makes it incompatible with adjustbox.

Thank you for your insights. You might be right that the issue stems from the nature template redefining the table environment. I will try adjusting the font size and spacing as an alternative to scale the table. Thanks again for your suggestion.
